# 4 elements set and a binary operation

Tags: group-theory, binary, axioms

As part of a larger problem I am working on, I need to come up with an example as follows:
A set of exactly 4 elements with a binary operation.
The set plus the operation have to comply with all the requirements of a group with the exception of the last one. I.e. Invertibility.
It can be a known operation or a made up one * with a table.
It is important though that invertibilty will not exist for a least one of the elements. 
In other words the 4 elements set, exhibits the first 3 qualities of a group but not the last one.

I tried thinking of a known operation such as addition but could not find an example that will maintain closure. With a made up operation and a table it is very difficult to check for associativity so I'm lost there as well.

Any help would be appreciated.
Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a set $A=\{1,2\}$ with two elements, now consider it's power set $$P(A)=\{\emptyset, \{1\}, \{2\}, \{1,2\}\}.$$ 
with four elements and the binary operation as intersection of two sets. $(P(A), \cap)$ is a monoid (group without requiring existence of inverses) with identity element as $A$ but inverse need not exist.

Comment: will I be able to just say that associativity exists in this set with ∩ or there needs to be prof provided. What I mean is that it is fairly known and acceptable that the intersection operation is assosiative  but not sure about showing that it also exists in this particular set.

Comment: @eventhorizon02 the associativity of the intersection operation is valid for any type of sets and is very well-known (a standard result) hence can be used without a need of proof (however the exact requirement will depend on the context in which this question was asked).

Answer (score 2):

A fairly obvious example is $Z_n=\{0,1,\ldots,n-1\}$ under the operation
of **multiplication** modulo $n$. (Here $n=4$.)

My other example (now deleted) was
$\{0,1,\ldots,n\}$ under the operation
$a*b=\min(a+b,n)$. (Here $n=3$.)

Comment: Your first example looks good. Is there a quick easy way to prove that associativity exists? I mean even for such a small set of 4 elements it's a lot of combinations to go through.

Comment: @eventhorizon02 It's surely well-known that multiplication of integers is associative?

Answer (score 1):

Ordinary multiplication, over the set $\left\{0,1,\frac{-1+\sqrt{-3}}{2},\frac{-1-\sqrt{-3}}{2}\right\}$.